# Extract coefficients from a list of estimation objects

Tags: r, lm

I saw some similar questions but my questions seems to be simpler.

I am running a more complicated regression than my MWE and end up with a list of estimation objects. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of extracting the coefficients of the list, than using another for loop over the number or names of the list.

```
list.lm<-list()
for(i in 1:3) {
list.lm[[i]]<-lm(mpg~cyl+runif(32), data=mtcars)
}
```

I know that I can use apply to get the coeffcients, but I cannot transform this

```
sapply(list.lm,coefficients)
```

or

```
 t(sapply(list.lm, coefficients))
```

ok then I can do

```
data.frame(iteration=seq(1,3),t(sapply(list.lm,coefficients)))
```

which is the same as with my loop

```
results<-data.frame(iteration=numeric(),intercept=numeric(), cyl=numeric(), rand=numeric())
for(i in 1:3) {
results[i,]<-c(iteration=i,coefficients(list.lm[[i]]))
}
results
```

Comment: `vapply(list.lm, coefficients, numeric(3))`

Comment: thats basically the same as the lapply, that i already have. Someone proposed to use transpose, but this has disapeared

Comment: Perhaps you should elaborate on what you're looking for. It looks to me like @Barker's solution takes your `results` code and reduces it to a single line of code, which is much more efficient.

Comment: I really needed the hint with transpose actually and I would accept this as an answer, but it's gone.

Comment: I just brought it back. I deleted it because of the DV and I assumed it was you and that you were looking for something wholly different, hence the comment above to clarify what you were looking for.

Comment: I all accepts yours, cause this what I was initially needed to solve my problem and it saved me a lot of time, because I would not have thought about using transpose. I don't really understand all the downvoting. It is not the most elaborate question, but beginners struggle with such "easy" things.

Comment: The down votes were because the question is unclear, not because the answer was simple.  Since you were asking for "a more elegant way of extracting the coefficients", it was not possible to tell from your question that your problem was with the format of the outputs rather than the efficiency of the code.

Comment: I would say using less lines of code to get to same results can also be considered efficient. Anyhow, I try to be more precise in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way would be to just use `sapply` and transpose the result, rather than `lapply`.

```
t(sapply(list.lm,coefficients))
#      (Intercept)       cyl runif(32)
# [1,]    35.43360 -2.774654  4.163870
# [2,]    38.71960 -2.840392 -1.896252
# [3,]    38.97739 -2.784622 -3.955039
```

You might also want to look into Hadley's `purrr` package and/or David Robinson's `broom` package. See https://blog.rstudio.org/2015/09/29/purrr-0-1-0/ and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/broom.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I just need to use transpose and sapply/vapply

```
data.frame(iteration=seq(1,3),t(sapply(list.lm,coefficients)))
```